# Owl carousel Navigation is inverted

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

It is a bit hard to explain what is happening. Basically, right now when I press the next button, it goes to the previous slide. If I press prev it goes to the next slide. I do have RTL enabled but is this how it is supposed to behave? I have made a small video for better understanding that can be found [**HERE**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Wnn-kaUNXm0LtkMNBV4yhWQMXROBmhl/view)

Any idea what is going on? Here is my code:

```
//slider rtl
    $('#owl-slider-rtl').owlCarousel({
            rtl: true,
            loop: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 6000, //Set AutoPlay to 6 seconds
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            nav: true,
            navText: ["<i class='ti-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='ti-angle-right'></i>"],
            items: 1,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                }
                , 479: {
                    items: 1
                }
                , 768: {
                    items: 1
                }
                , 980: {
                    items: 1
                }
                , 1199: {
                    items: 1
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 thm-padding">
                            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                                <div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                    <!-- Slider item ... Multiple of these -->
                                    <div class="item">
                                        <div class="slider-post post-height-1">
                                            <a href="#" class="news-image"><img src="assets/images/slider-695x460-5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                                            <div class="post-text">
                                                <span class="post-category">Technology</span>
                                                <h2><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard </a></h2>
                                                <ul class="authar-info">
                                                    <li class="authar"><a href="#">by david hall</a></li>
                                                    <li class="date">May 29,2016</li>
                                                    <li class="view"><a href="#">25 views</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.Slider item five -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Is this the default behavior of RTL? Or is there an error within the code/html?

Answer (score 0):

you must edit you css according to rtl also

```
.owl-next {
left: 0;
right: initial;
}
.owl-prev {
right: 0;
left: initial;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not help. It just changes the buttons layout but not the actual function. Is this a bug? Ot did I do something wrong?

Comment: @BasicBud It's not a bug in the owl carousel but this happens when use custom theme.. this will invert the location of the buttons
if you have use custom nav links you must also change it according to rtl
for better examining your code it's better you upload it somewhere

Comment: But there is another issue. I have a fancybox image gallery wrapped inside of the owl carousel because I wanted the owl carousel images to be viewable when clicked. And when the images are enlarged, the same effect is being applied to the nav buttons of fancybox. So that means it’s not CSS right? Though the fancybox is wrapped inside of owl carousel, the fancybox enlarged image navigation should not act as owl carousel right? I do not think this is css and buttons?

Comment: @BasicBud even if it's images they need css to position properly and you may have to invert the icon when you do that

Comment: So I have to inverse the icons of fancybox as well? Why is fancybox navigation being effected?

Answer (score 0):

Just swap your nav buttons:

```
navText: ["<i class='ti-angle-right'></i>", "<i class='ti-angle-left'></i>"]
```

And apply `direction: rtl;` to the `owl-nav` container. So you invert both slides and nav.
Worked for me